# Magnetic flux through a current carrying square loop

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

[image]
It seems to me that the value of magnetic flux through a square loop(side=a) must be finite but my attempt at solving doesnt seem to give me the correct answer

my attempt(sorry i am new so i do not know how to use math text very well):
taking the area of small elements=dx*dy

$$b_t=b1+b2+b3+b4$$

$$\phi=\int_0^a\int_0^a b_t*dx*dy$$

but the problem arises with the limits as at any extreme when we approach a wire the field tends ->$\infty$

where have i gone wrong or is my initial assumption that it is finite itself wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE. Can you provide some context because we don't know anything about the question and where you are facing difficulty.

Comment: A sketch of the problem with proper labels would be very useful.

Comment: yes sure can i post a picture as I do not know how to upload a diagram through this website?

Comment: Field tends to be infinity does not mean flux will be infinity. Your calculation may be correct.

Comment: @verdelite well i thought so too but when applying limits i got a ln(0) term

Comment: Consider that the field from a finite length of straight current varies from point to point in a complex fashion.  Then consider that the field of a real wire has its maximum at the surface of the wire which has a finite radius.

Comment: @R.W.Bird so then for an ideal wire the flux is infinite?